# Export a large number of SQL Server tables to SQL file via command-line?

Tags: sql, sql-server, export

I want to export the CREATE codes (sans data) of nearly 400 tables from SQL Server.

My usual go-to, HeidiSQL, lists every single database object in a giant list of thousands of selection boxes (including views, procedures, and tables I don't care about) in its SQL export tool.

My question is if there is a command-line tool that can achieve the same thing when I feed it the list of table names (of which I have in a text file). Really, I'm looking for anything more efficient than clicking nearly 400 selection boxes.

Any ideas?

Comment: When using SSMS (SQL Server Management Studio) you could use the Object Explorer Detail tab.